# get_terms only show term if there is a post using it

Tags: terms

I have a custom post type called `user_images`. I would like to create some filters and populate the dropdowns dynamically. I am using the follow code:

```
$post_type = 'user_images';
$taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies((object) array('post_type' => $post_type));
$terms = get_terms('image_categories');
foreach( $terms as $term ){
  echo $term->name;
}
```

This is correctly listing my custom taxonomy `Image Categories` but it is showing terms even if none of the posts have that term assigned to it. How can I only list out the terms which are associated with posts and within this specific custom post type?

Comment: Maybe you can look at `object_ids` and `hide_empty` of `get_terms()`? I think there was a similar question here recently but can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`get_terms` should hide empty terms by default, but you can force it to setting `hide_empty` argument to true:

```
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'image_categories',
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );
```